# How can I build an IOS app

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am attempting to run my app an iOS device but I can't seem to figure it out.  This is the question. I am unsure of how to add a device to run it on because I never had to do it before. I release this is a fairly simple question but I searched this site and Google very hard and was unable to find an answer that I could understand.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all Go to your apple developer account and create an app certifications for development and distribution (Skip this step if you have credentials already).
2. Create new app identifier which you need to specify your bundle identifier.
3. Create or select the device which your app is going to run.
4. Create a signing entity (provisional profile) which is authorised for the specific app and select the created app identifier and list of device(s) to run the app. **Make sure** that you're using the same app identifier (Bundle identifier in your app).
5. Generate your certificates and that's all done from the account perspective.
6. Open xcode and goto preferences. Choose the account which is associated with the certification created for the app.
7. Refresh the account certification to download the recent copy of the certifications.
8. Go to build settings of your app and in the signing entity section, you'll see lot of rows. Blindly choose iOS developer (if you want to test on your device) or iOS distribution (if you want to distribute the app) and the last row, select your created provisional profile.
9. That's all. Start testing and sharing!!

If you want to build the app use **Command+B** and for running the app, use **Command+R**.

Hope the above steps helps you... Please do let me know, if you need more help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

here i am getting finally answer

xcode>product>build

or press command+f5 button...

Comment: you are correct mr.varma as you are new person so do some more googling sp that you can got the answer quickly you dont have to put such small question anyways best up luck for next time...

Comment: ok next time i wil take care about this things...

Answer (score 0):

1. You must have an iOS developer account.
2. Add UDID of your device to developer account.
3. Create iOS App IDs
4. Create and add Provisioning Profiles to XCode
5. Connect your device to Mac
6. Select device and run

Follow this [Deploying iPhone Apps to Real Devices](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices)

Answer (score 0):

read carefully the tutorial at Apple ADC site, are really well written.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/

Comment: please give some code or notes not the link